# How to search category and fill site parameters automatically

Tags: seo

I have seen some sites where you search (in Google) for a particular item category and when you click the link found in Google it automatically goes to the site clicked with the search criteria filled in displaying the categorised products.

**Hypothetical Example** 
Go into Google type in Sony TV , click to search.
Results are displayed.
Clicking one of the links takes me to a website which shows all the Sony TV models beginning with AA.
Looking at the search options on the page some fields have been automatically filled in (in other words if you did this search manually the site would prompt you to enter some search criteria) - Not sure if this is relevant but thought to mention.

How is this done? Do i need to setup something in our Google account to get the same results?

Comment: You need to provide sitemap to Google. This is more of a seo question than a specific technology.

Comment: Tag changed - I have a sitemap file on the site which has been automatically been created by a site found online - Is there a particular site i should be using to do this or certain elements i need to include?

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple. You pass parameters in your URLs that identify the product, and then you just read the URL parameters when pre-populating the search form on the page. When building your site / sitemap / internal & external links you use those page URLs and Google will naturally pick them up.

In your example, you search for Sony TV. One of the results may be

```
example.com/index.php?product=sony-tv
```

The website has the variable sony-tv, which it gets from the URL and pre-populates on the search form.

The important part to note is that the site will have built its URL structure in this method typically and the page you're presented with just happens to look like the site dynamically searched based on your query (it hasn't).

Comment: Thanks - my site page currently doesnt accept a search criteria but it only takes in an ID, so if Sony is ID 1 then my URL looks like example.com/ourproducts?cid=1 - so are you saying this needs to be changed or is there another way to achieve the same?